# Interstellar electron velocity distributions

Tags: interstellar-matter

I've found an [estimation](http://www.ias.ac.in/jarch/jaa/3/399-412.pdf) for interstellar electron density which ranges from $3.0 \times 10^4$ electrons per cubic meter (pcm), to $5.0 \times 10^4$ electrons pcm close to the galactic plane.

However, this estimation doesn't provide any range for velocity distributions. What is the most accurate estimate/measurement of average interstellar velocity distributions for electrons?

Comment: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.1666v1.pdf , http://arxiv.org/pdf/1108.4822v1.pdf